# Get full old record before save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I need to backup a record before save. Not only the changes that were made (I know to do it with `Person.name_was`) but **ALL, COMPLETE** record.

I.E. something like `Person_was`. But there is no such method.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this code:

```
person_history = PersonHistory.new
person.attributes.except("id", "password").each{ |key, value| eval("person_history.#{key} = person.#{key}_was")}
person_history.save
```

Comment: Not sure how this helps you. Given that it appears you are dropping the `id`, how are you linking `PersonHistory` to a `Person`? Additionally there are much cleaner ways to implement than `eval` e.g. `person_history.public_send("#{key}=", person.public_send("#{key}_was"))` or even easier `PersonHistory.new(person.attributes.except("id", "password")).save` should work.